# Boot loop Samsung GALAXY Note 10.1 N8013

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

My tablet is stuck booting. I can't get it into recovery. When I hold Power+VolumeUp it goes into "Custom OS ..." with exclamation sign in yellow triangle. Then I press VolumeUp again to go into ODIN download mode. But when I try to flash CWM recovery (or anything else) it goes into "waiting for debugging mode" or "waiting for adb mode". Windows ODIN shows COMM and allows to flush boot loader, but without any difference. I tried everything, including opening up the unit and disconnecting the battery. I can't even turn it off - the screen turns off but when I press power again - it comes right back to Samsung logo. Please help! Thank you.
[image][image]

Comment: I used the n8013 for about 3 years, and I remember coming across a similar issue when I tried installing cm. From the little experience I gained, I'll recommend you try using Heimdall for the whole flashing process if you can instead. Simply relax. When that android with open stomach comes up, does your ADB/Fastboot works? If so, then you're good to go using Heimdall. You can find a ton of how to use Heimdall with Samsung devices online

Comment: @Rexford "When that android with open stomach comes up, does your ADB/Fastboot works?" I only see Android in ODIN mode and when I try Fastboot it sows "waiting for ADB mode". I also tried command line and it showed "error".

Comment: I do not know the documentation you're following, but since you're looking to flash cyanogenmod, how about you try the official documentation using the holy grail heimdall? https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_n8013 **NOTE**: Be very very sure the USB cable you are using is correct and properly functioning, as you might end up spoiling the device with a faulty cable. Or you might get weird feedbacks/results.

Answer (score 0):

If all else failed
1. Put Stock ROM On SD Card
2. Boot into Download Mode
3. Install starts automatically !
For SD Card Booting ROM Updates,
it requires you to rename the ROM File To a    device specific name Eg. SGH100463.zip.

I can't find any zip files for reference but i found this info on the download mode

> Download Mode for Samsung devices allows you to install new OTA Updates by pushing them from your computer directly to your phone using only a data cable.
>
> Also, for your computer to work with the Download Mode you will need to have the ODIN software present.

Comment: Cite your source? and include more information on the .zip files?

Comment: I can't find any, Googling Download Mode and Odin Shows most relevant info

Comment: I placed the below stock ROM zip on external SD card went to ODIN download mode - it stays there and nothing happens as picture above shows. http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/58145/N8013UEUCOI1_N8013XARCOI1_XAR/

Comment: Did you open Odin on pc and connect the cable ? .  OR PRESS VOLUME UP

Comment: Yes,  I also connected cable and loaded the same ROM zip via ODIN successfully, but after restart the tablet still shows Samsung logo until the batterty is dead (I can't even turn it off).